# How do i change the Wordpress Attachment Permalinks?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, attachment

Ok so i have been researching this for hours but nothing.

I have my permalinks on wordpress set like this

> /year-month-day/posttitle

but i want the attachments to like differently. I want my attachments to link like this

> /category/postitle/attachment

so basically, all i ant to change is the "year-month-day" to "category" only for the attachments.

Can anyone help me with this please? :)

Comment: Maybe this could give you some help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5015/attachment-url-rewrite

Comment: hey @intrepidd thats not exactly what i'm looking for :(

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532508/how-to-change-the-attachment-url-in-wordpress

Comment: Hey mcometa, thats not it either, that only changes attachment to media. I ant to change it from "year-month-year/postname/attachment" to "category/postname/attachment"

Comment: how about this ? http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-permalink-add

Answer (score -2):

Log in to your wordpress >> go to settings >> press "permalinks" >> choose your permalink format

If you want anything specific, you can choose "Custom Structure" instead of the last step.

Hope this helps!